# Camera switching in blender game engine 2.72

Tags: game-engine, camera, selection-tools

I am making a game in Blender 2.72, but in version 1.5a I decided to make a multiple camera view feature. I want it so that when you press <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>(both are to do the same thing) the cameras will switch. I tried some tutorials, in which it was shown that actuators should work. I did all as said, but when I tested the game, it did not work as expected. I tried two different ways:

```
1.State 1
Keyboard C ------ And (state1) -------- State (set: 2)
Kayboard F3 ------/                  \- Scene (set camera: cam2)
State 2
Keyboard C ------ And (state2) ----------- State (set:1)
Keyboard F3 ---/                       \-- Scene (set camera: cam1)

2. State 1
Always(pulse) ------- And(state1) --------- Scene (set camera: cam1)
Keyboard C --------- And(state1) ---------- State (set: 2)
Keyboard F3 --/
State 2
Always(pulse) --------And(state2) ---------Scene (set camera: cam2)
Keyboard C ----------- And(state2) -------- State (set:1)
Keyboard F3 --/
```

Neither of these methods appears to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!
I found an answer:
This logic does not work, if 2 Keyboard sensors are connected to one And controller. Making different And controllers for each of buttons(C and F3) fixed this thing. Now it works for me!:)